# For a video game that player can build up his own character, any copyright issue if the character similar to Mario, Gundam etc?

Tags: copyright

The video game do not provide any particular character. It only provides parts for player to build up his own character, such as hat, head, eye, mouth, chest, abdomen, pelvis, shoulder etc. more than 15 parts for a complete character.

And there are around 20 choice for each part, so the combination is something like 20^15 times.

I wonder if there is still any copyright problem if player create his own character that similar to famous animation or game character, such as Gundam?

Comment: The number of combinations or how they arise is irrelevant. Either you allow copyrighted content to be recreated or you don't, and that either is or not a breach regardless.

Comment: Assuming you don't want to use this questionable user-generated-content in your own marketing materials, there can still be other kinds of problems that arise from publicly hosting such content and you may have to obey DMCA requests to take down such content if they come up.

Comment: @Nij The number of combinations is relevant in that it's undoubtedly the user creating the content.  If there were like 5 possibilities and one of them looked like Mario, then that's really the game creating it.

Comment: If you have Mario's hat, Mario's face, Mario's body, Mario's arms, Mario's legs, Mario's feet and Mario's wrench all obviously available, that's going to be just the same as if you stuck the whole Mario together for them first. @DM I don't see an argument supporting the use regardless of what else could have been randomly generated.

Comment: If a small part can breach copyright, any red hat with "M" in the middle is not allowed to use in any game, because it is mario's hat?

Comment: @Nij "Mario's face" isn't something you can just select. The user can select the color and shape of, say, the eyes/ears/nose/mustache/mouth/hair/hat/etc. This allows them to get pretty close to Mario's face, even if that was never intended by the game creator. And "Either you allow copyrighted content to be recreated or you don't" seems like a ridiculous standard. Reducto ad absurdum, by that standard even this comments box is infringing, since someone can type letters and words that combine into a copyrighted work.

Comment: Then how creation is possible nowadays? A red hat with "M" belong to Mario's, a round big nose belong to Mario's, round eyes belong to Mario's, a red laser saber belong to gundam or star war.

Comment: @Shitman A red hat with an M or a light saber alone is probably not enough.  But if you create many similar elements (e.g. by hand drawing them) and combine these to create a character that looks like Mario, or that looks like a Jedi, that could be considered infringement.

Answer (score 0):

I would look for the case that was basically City of Heroes vs. Marvel Entertainment.  In this case City of Heroes was a superhero mmo game that allowed users a diverse choice in avatar creation.  Marvel filed suit claiming that the game allowed players to make characters based on Marvel properties (wolverine was particularly egregious as the entire Claws power set at the time had weapons that looked like his trade mark claw, but other characters existed).  Ultimately it was settled out of court when it turned out Marvel had made their evidence using the system and it wasn't other players using the game.  The net effect was that City of Heroes staff became more attentive to people who made characters based off of existing properties and would restrict the variation of the name used and give the player a generic name.

Terms of service of most online games do say that player generated content is technically the property of the game and it's license holders so had Marvel actually screen capped player violations (which did happen frequently) there might have been some merit.  Either way, if the game owner feels that a third party character was introduced by the player, they typically will get rid of the character to avoid licensing issues with that character's IP owner.

In short, yes, there is a copyright issue, but due to the Terms of Agreement these issues fall under the the game owner's problems, not yours.  Essentially if a player makes mario in the character creator, than the game owner is basically forced to make claim to owning Mario.  The ramification to the player is that your Mario look alike will be deleted or otherwise modified to prevent the copyright issue hitting the company.  You may not have any investments returned to you including character slots, rename tokens, or what have you and they could ban you if persistent... but this is not any legal responsibility on your part.

Comment: So character design system in a game is very high risk to game owner? There are so many animation and game characters created in decades, more or less a game will "copy" some parts that were used in other characters before. Say, for a T-shirt, if a game allow player to select the T-Shirt Color, and type words on the T-Shift.  If a player select blue color and type"S". Then it look like Superman chest, and the game owner is in trouble. If the player select red color and write two square, then it look like Optimus Prime chest.  Isn't it a bit ridiculous?

Comment: @Shitman Just because you write an S on a T-Shirt does not mean you are trying to copy a Superman design. You would have to look at the actual example of supposed copying. And certainly if you own a Superman design you will need more evidence of copying than just saying that someone wrote the letter S on a shirt.

Comment: T-Shirt is just example, the key point here is a character design system in game, a good system is to be able to select shape, color, texture for a model. When a character is subdivided into so many small parts, and each part is editable, it is very easy for player to create any particular character. (you can imagine the game itself includes a simple 3D model software) And the answer so far seem to support the game owner breach copyright, who just create a very flexible modeling software in game. This is the part I don't understand.

Comment: @Shitman:  It's a bit rediculous but unfortunately, it's easier for the game to take a stance on the use of creating blatant copyrighted characters at the beginning and policing them, then they don't have to deal with the lawyers.  Some companies, like Disney and Warner Bros (who own Superman) are notoriously litigious over copyright infringement.  And while "Fair Use" can be a defense for some of these actions, it's an affirmative defense, meaning it doesn't apply automatically.

Comment: A few issues with this answer. A case that settled out of court has little precedental value - but you fail to note that the court actually dismissed some of the claims before it settled. Even if a particular ToS makes a particular game liable, that doesn't mean the player isn't *also* liable - if a player does something infringing, they can be sued by the copyright owner regardless of what contracts the player has with other parties. I'd also point to 17 U.S. Code § 204 which require copyright transfers to be actually signed; clickwrap isn't good enough for that.